# Error while fetching email with oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am  trying to get 2-legged OAuth to work with the Gmail atom feed.I am using correct key and secret and already tested with task and calendar  but the same is not working for email
Snippet of code is:

```
import static net.oauth.OAuth.HMAC_SHA1;     
import static net.oauth.OAuth.OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD;  
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Map;  
import net.oauth.OAuthAccessor;
import net.oauth.OAuthConsumer;
import net.oauth.OAuthMessage; 
import net.oauth.ParameterStyle;
import net.oauth.SimpleOAuthValidator;
import net.oauth.client.OAuthClient;  


import net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4; 
/**  * Sample application demonstrating how to do 2-Legged OAuth in the Google Data  * Java Client. 
 *  See the comments below to learn about the details.              *               
 *  
*/     
public class GmailAtomFeed2LeggedOauth {  
public static String CONSUMER_KEY = "key";  
public static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "secret";   
public static String SCOPE = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";  
public static String RESOURCE_URL = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";   
public static String SERVICE_NAME = "mail";                               
public static String username = "name";                                
public static boolean debug = true;                                         
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
// This should be passed in as a parameter         
String user = username + "@" + CONSUMER_KEY;  
OAuthConsumer consumer = new OAuthConsumer(null, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, null);     
OAuthAccessor accessor = new OAuthAccessor(consumer);                                 
// HMAC uses the access token secret as a factor,      
// and it's a little less compute-intensive than RSA.     
accessor.consumer.setProperty(OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD, HMAC_SHA1);    
// Gmail only supports an atom feed     
URL atomFeedUrl = new URL(SCOPE +"?xoauth_requestor_id=" + user);    
System.out.println("=====================================================");      
System.out.println("Building new request message...");      
OAuthMessage request = accessor.newRequestMessage(OAuthMessage.GET, atomFeedUrl.toString(),null);   
if (debug) {        
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> params = request.getParameters();       
     for (Map.Entry<String, String> p : params) {             

    System.out.println("'" + p.getKey() + "' =  <" + p.getValue() + ">");     
    }             System.out.println("Validating message...");     
    SimpleOAuthValidator validator=new SimpleOAuthValidator();         
    validator.validateMessage(request,accessor);    
    }  
OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new HttpClient4());   
System.out.println("Client invoking request message...");   
System.out.println(" request: " + request);        
OAuthMessage message = client.invoke(request, ParameterStyle.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
System.out.println("message==============="+message);
System.out.println("=====================================================");     
System.out.println(" message: " + message.readBodyAsString());       
System.out.println("=====================================================");   
} 

}
```

I am getting exception when invoke function is called

```
request: OAuthMessage(GET, https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom?xoauth_requestor_id=myid@mydomain.com, [oauth_consumer_key=mykey, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_timestamp=1331642083, oauth_nonce=118947882606867, oauth_version=1.0, oauth_signature=xbqiCZWqFNjX3mk1dbN8zuT%2BTMs%3D])
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase from class net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4
at net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4.execute(HttpClient4.java:86)
at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.access(OAuthClient.java:317)
at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.invoke(OAuthClient.java:304)
at com.a2o.service.collaboration.common.GmailAtomFeed2LeggedOauth.main(GmailAtomFeed2LeggedOauth.java:62)
```

Any idea why I am getting this exception.